# Openpyxl - Writing from dictionary to excel rows and columns

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

So what im trying to do is writing to an existing excel-file from a dictionary:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename='test.xlsx')
ws2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Blad3")
tuple(ws2.iter_rows('A2:I1000'))
for i in ws2.iter_rows('A2:I1000'):
    print str(row[0].value)
    for i in Candidates:
        row[0].value = i['Start Location']
        row[1].value = i['Distance']
        row[2].value = i['End Location']
    for p in Potential_candidates:
        row[4].value = p['Start Location']
        row[5].value = p['Distance']
        row[6].value = p['End Location']
    for n in No_coords:
        row[8].value = No_coords
print 'Saving to file "test.xlsx"'
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

the "print str(row[0].value)" get the correct value from the worksheet, but when i instead try to set the value it says:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'.

The error occurs at row[0].value = i['Start Location']

Ive been trying to figure out why and either ive just missed the most obvious thing or im completely lost. Shouldnt you be able to write to the cell if you 
can read from it?

So i figured out what was wrong with the NoneType error, apparently the list had a None element at [0]. 
So i added a function to remove such elements from all the lists and now i have a new error:

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: What is the 3rd line (`tuple(ws2.iter_rows('A2:I1000'))`) doing?

Comment: Oh, that doesnt really do anything, it was more a reminder for myself. ironacally i get remember what it was a reminder for :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured out what i did wrong, which was alot, first of, my code tried to fill each row with the entire dictionary instead of just the first element.
Secondly row[0]= didnt work because of... reasons. So i did a messy solution (but that works):

```
def write_excel():
wb = load_workbook(filename='test.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Blad3")
count = 0
for row in ws.iter_rows('A2:I500'):
    x = str(row[0].coordinate)
    x1 = str(row[1].coordinate)
    x2 = str(row[2].coordinate)
    x3 = str(row[4].coordinate)
    x4 = str(row[5].coordinate)
    x5 = str(row[6].coordinate)
    x6 = str(row[8].coordinate)
    try:
        Start = Candidates[count]['Start Location']
        Dist = Candidates[count]['Distance']
        End = Candidates[count]['End Location']
        ws[x] = Start
        ws[x1] = Dist
        ws[x2] = End
    except IndexError:   
        pass
    try:
        Pstart = Potential_candidates[count]['Start Location']
        Pdist = Potential_candidates[count]['Distance']
        Pend = Potential_candidates[count]['End Location']
        ws[x3] = Pstart
        ws[x4] = Pdist
        ws[x5] = Pend
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        NoCoo = No_coords[count]
        ws[x6] = NoCoo
    except IndexError:
        pass
    count=count+1
print 'Saving to file "test.xlsx"'
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

I know it can be cleaned up alot, but it helped me to understand what went poopoo so hopefully it might help someone else as well :)
Ill be cleaned up when i create a better codestructure for the whole program.